# Injecting javascript into dom, from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to inject a script into the DOM but the script is not actually ran. What am I doing wrong? The console.log is not executed.

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<div class="x"><script type="application/javascript">console.log("a");</script></div>';
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? And give a demo so that we can easily figure out the problem

Comment: Did you try this? : `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<div id="x"></div>'; document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = '<script type="application/javascript">console.log("a");</script>';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() method to run dynamic scripts. But it is not recommended to run script dynamically due to security issues.